# Pandas masked dataframe assign 2D array

Tags: pandas, numpy, mask

I'm trying to solve a riddle with dataframe and masked array.

**Context**
I'm trying to make some methods to help me with some machine learning stuff. My goals is from a simple dataframe to add new information to it. I want these functions as simple to use.

**Problem**
This is a function that take what I called a model, and can make a transform from data. Then, I want to set these new data on new or existing column. I'm not using apply function because, if I do it, I'm losing the ability to extract several data at once with parrallism (that's why I'm extracting first then applying the 'features'.

Here is the riddle, I want to work with a mask because without this mask I cannot modify the original dataframe. If you remove this mask,if dataframe and features have the same number of lines everything is fine. Now, if I add this mask, it seems to be taken row by row and dimension mismatch....
EDIT: I forgot to tell that 'features' correspond to a 2d numpy array.

**Error**

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray

**Code**

```
def transform(dataframe, tags, out, model, mask=None):
    # Check mandatory fields
    mandatory = ['datum']
    if not isinstance(tags, dict) or not all(elem in mandatory for elem in tags.keys()):
        raise Exception(f'Not a dict or missing tag: {mandatory}.')

    # Mask creation (see pandas view / copy mechanism)
    if mask is None:
        mask = [True] * len(dataframe.index)

    features = model.transform(dataframe.loc[mask, tags['datum']].to_numpy())
    dataframe.loc[mask, out] = features.tolist()
    return dataframe
```

**Example**
Data can be something like this:

Row ; Data  ; Label

0   ; [61953.017837947686, 9.505037089204054, 74.585... ] ;0

1   ; [80832.69302693632, 9.524642547991316, 83.9228... ] ;1

A model could be a PCA from sklearn.
The method could be something like this:

```
transform(dataframe, {'datum': 'Data'}, 'PCA', PCA(), mask=dataframe[dataframe['Label']==1)
```

Then output would be:

Row ; Data  ; Label ; PCA

0   ; [61953.017837947686, 9.505037089204054, 74.585... ] ;0 ; [74.585... ]

1   ; [80832.69302693632, 9.524642547991316, 83.9228... ] ;1 ; [92.578... ]

**Current solution**

```
mask = inputs[condition]
inputs['PCA'] = np.nan
inputs[mask] = Classification.transform(inputs[mask], {'datum': 'Data'}, wavelet, 'PCA')

def transform(dataframe, tags, model, out):
    # Check mandatory fields
    mandatory = ['datum']
    if not isinstance(tags, dict) or not all(elem in mandatory for elem in tags.keys()):
        raise Exception(f'Not a dict or missing tag: {mandatory}.')

    features = model.transform(dataframe[tags['datum']].to_numpy())
    dataframe[out] = features.tolist()
    return dataframe
```

Thanks for answers!
Best regards

Comment: It would be great to get more of an example of what you are trying to do here by showing a real example of the type of transform you would be doing, with input data and expected outputs

Comment: I updated as you asked for ;)

Comment: Can you try `dataframe.loc[mask, [out]] = features.tolist()` (notice extra square brackets)? If that doesn't work, printing what `features.shape` is would be helpful. Out of interest, what are the subsequently using this for? Curious if there is a better way to get you where you need to be,

Comment: Thanks for you're reactivity !
So for `dataframe.loc[mask, [out]] = features.tolist()`, I'm getting "None of [Index(['PCA'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
For your second question, `features.shape` have a dimension of (600, 12) and the dataframe have 600 rows.
For your final question, my main purpose was to make a tool library to use it in jupyter notebook in the most readible way, to achieve some research about classification.

Comment: I added a solution that doesn't really what I need for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I find a solution that fit my needs.
Second idea was according to me a bad idea, as it seems not easy to pass view as argument and edit it with a convenient way.

So, I change my first proposition. Here is the final version:

```
def transform(dataframe, tags, model, out, mask=None):
    # Check mandatory fields
    mandatory = ['datum']
    if not isinstance(tags, dict) or not all(elem in mandatory for elem in tags.keys()):
        raise Exception(f'Not a dict or missing tag: {mandatory}.')

    # Mask creation (see pandas view / copy mechanism)
    if mask is None:
        mask = [True] * len(dataframe.index)

    # dataframe[out] = np.nan
    features = model.transform(dataframe.loc[mask, tags['datum']].to_numpy())
    dataframe.loc[mask, out] = pd.Series(features.tolist())
    return dataframe
```

Instead of doing dataframe.loc[mask, out] = features.tolist(), I switch to : dataframe.loc[mask, out] = pd.Series(features.tolist()). By going through a Series it fit without any problems.

Thanks Ken Syme to be involved in my problem.